# Oracle Result Cache statistics

Tags: sql, oracle, caching

I am using `/*+ result_cache */` optimizer hint as well `RESULT_CACHE`in my function.
When i run the query:

```
select * from v$result_cache_objects;
```

i can see that my objects are present in cache but i want to know hit and miss stats. Like how many queries were fired, how many hit cache and how many missed it.
Is there a way that i get these details?

Comment: what is version of ORACLE, 11g or 12c? for 12c Use  select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cusrsor())

Comment: Its 12c but how will explain plan help? Will it have cache stats in it?

Comment: yes please share the output of my query.

Comment: The find count in the V$RESULT_CACHE_STATISTICS view will give you the number of cached results that were successfully found. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/dynviews_2133.htm

Answer (score 1):

The query on [v$result_cache_objects](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/refrn/V-RESULT_CACHE_OBJECTS.html#GUID-2DA2EDEA-8B1D-42E6-A293-663B3124AAFD) is correct to find how often a cache is used.  Look at the SCAN_COUNT column which gives the total number of scans initiated on the cached result.

To see statistics for the whole system you can query [v$result_cache_statistics](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/refrn/V-RESULT_CACHE_STATISTICS.html#GUID-9E89646B-102D-4211-A181-DDF96F809289).  Specifically, "Create Count Success" will show you how many cache results were created and "Find Copy Count" will show you how many cache results were found and copied directly out of the cache.